# $filter array field using array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

my collection record for mongodb

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ba60b805f13dc37a5377302"),
  "clientID" : "5ba49a5b58db5fb63b282565",
  "propertyID" : "77f3d86a9842afa8ee7a64f3bf958ef4",
  "emod" : [ 
    {
        "audience" : "Mobile",
        "emodID" : "5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37",

     }, 
    {
        "audience" : "Laptop",
        "emodID" : "5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37",
    }, 
    {
        "audience" : "Games",
        "emodID" : "5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37"
    }]
}
```

find record query

```
var audienceList = ["Mobile","Laptop"];

predictionCollection.findOne({
    "clientID": '5ba49a5b58db5fb63b282565',
}, {
    emod: {
        $elemMatch: {
            'audience': {"$in":audienceList}
        }
    },

}).exec(function (err, predictionData) {
```

output for predictionData

```
emod: [ { audience: 'Mobile', emodID: '5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37' } ] }
```

but i require output

```
emod: [ { audience: 'Mobile', emodID:'5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37' },
            { audience: 'Laptop', emodID:'5ba5e0f47b07641eeebfad37' }
    ] }

});
```

i am using mongo aggregration

i have also used $elementMatch and $in to match all array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) only returns first element from the array.

So, you need to use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator to retrive all the elements that matches condition

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "clientID": "5ba49a5b58db5fb63b282565" }},
  { "$project": {
    "emod": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$emod",
        "as": "em",
        "cond": { "$in": ["$$em.audience", ["Mobile", "Laptop"]] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: thank you for answer
but error occure for Unrecognized pipeline stage name: \'$addFields\''

    so, $addFields working on mongo 3.2.10 ??
    MY MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10

Comment: another error occure 
 name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'invalid operator \'$in\'',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'invalid operator \'$in\'',
  code: 15999 }

Comment: You have to upgrade your version to 3.4 or above to use above aggregation.